# Why is NSString stringWithString returning pointer to copied string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to copy an `NSString` value out of an `NSMutableArray` into a new variable. `NSString stringWithString` is returning an `NSString` with the same memory address as the object in my array. Why?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"first"];

        NSLog(@"string is '%@' %p", [arr objectAtIndex:0], [arr objectAtIndex:0]);

        // copy the string
        NSString *copy = [NSString stringWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"string is '%@' %p", copy, copy);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why is that happening, but have you tried doing `NSString *copy = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] copy];`

Comment: I have, it had the same result - the memory addresses matched.

Comment: The reason I'm needing to do this because in my real app the array is passed in as an argument to my method and is being disposed later. When it gets disposed I'm losing my NSString even though I've "copied" it out of the array.

Comment: And what about `NSString * str = [NSString stringWithCString:[[arr objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: @silent__thought: If that's your real problem, then the trouble is that the method you're using to "copy" the string doesn't grant you ownership over the result. `stringWithString:` returns an unowned object. Use `copy` or `alloc`/`initWithString:` to get an owned version. The pointers will still be the same, but the reference counting will be correct and the object will live.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter - thank you! That was the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Whenever you're creating a string using the `@""` syntax, the framework will automatically cache the string. `NSString` is a very special class, but the framework will take care of it. When you use `@"Some String"` in multiple places of your app, they will all point to the same address in memory. Only when you're using something like `-initWithData:encoding`, the string won't be cached.

2) The other answers suggested that you should use `-copy` instead, but `-copy` will only create a copy of the object if the object is mutable. (like NSMutableString)
When you're sending `-copy` to an immutable object (like NSString), it'll be the same as sending it `-retain` which returns the object itself.

```
NSString *originalString = @"Some String";
NSString *copy = [originalString copy];
NSString *mutableCopy1 = [originalString mutableCopy];
NSString *mutableCopy2 = [mutableCopy copy];
NSString *anotherString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:originalString];
```

--> `originalString`, `copy`, `mutableCopy2` and `anotherString` will all point to the same memory address, only `mutableCopy1` points do a different region of memory.

Comment: @Fabain if this is the case then if we make any change on value of *copy variable , why this change does not reflect on *originalString value.

Comment: @i_Intiution You can't make changes to immutable objects.

Answer (score 4):

Since `NSString` instances are not mutable, the `+stringWithString:` method is simply returning the input string with an incremented reference count.

If you *really* want to force the creating of a new, identical string, try:

```
NSString * copy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]];
```

There is little point in doing so, though, unless you need the pointer to be unique for some other reason...