# Memory addresses of two NSString objects having same string value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these two NSString pointers the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605851/why-are-these-two-nsstring-pointers-the-same)

Will the memory addresses of s1 & s2 be same?

If Yes, then Why?

What if both strings are mutable?

```
NSString *s1 = @"Hello";

NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is NSString stringWithString: returning pointer to copied string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890814), [Why are these two NSString pointers the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605851/), and [Difference between NSString literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032375/), probably [among others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+nsstring+address+same&submit=search)

Answer (score 2):

> Will the memory addresses of s1 & s2 be same?

maybe -- implementation is defined by Foundation.

> If Yes, then Why?

the implementation may return the parameter when and if no copy needs to be made -- the object you request behaves identical to the input parameter when the input parameter is an immutable `NSString`. when passing the immortal `NSString` literal as you have done, the implementation could easily determine that the parameter is immutable, and opt to return the parameter (`retained`).

of course, that's an optimization the library (Foundation) would need to recognize and support.

it's also possible that the implementation may elect *not* to return the input parameter, due to variances in implementation details. as one example, the implementation may return a new string if the string were created using an externally owned character buffer. it may also recognize the parameter is mutable, then would of course need to return a new immutable object representation.

> What if both strings are mutable?

then deep copying is more probable -- implementation is defined by Foundation. however, you will have unique instances (their addresses will not match).